# How i can change a style of one component in Styled-Components without create a new component?

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I have in my file LoginWrapper.js the import of the Material Design Grid:

```
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';
```

I'm trying to change this component:

```
import styled from 'styled-components'
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';

const GridMaterial = styled(Grid)`
    height: 100vh;
    backgroundColor: red;
`

export default GridMaterial;
```

How i can apply this style GridMaterial in my grid? I imported in my archive LoginWrapper.js the styles:

```
import LoginStyles from './login-form/LoginStyles'
```

And tried to put this in my component:

```
 <Grid className={LoginStyles.GridMaterial} container component="main">
```

But this styles don't apply in my grid component.

Comment: Check the Material-UI [style document](https://material-ui.com/styles/basics/)

Comment: Did you try `<GridMaterial />` ?

Comment: @ksav i don't wanna create a new component, just change styles from the existing component

Comment: @keikai i will read

Comment: GridMaterial is a component, not a style. It's a "styled component". So just render it like a normal component.

Comment: you can directly use `<GridMaterial` why `<Grid className={LoginStyles.GridMaterial} container component="main">`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way;

```
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

const useStyles= makeStyles({
  gridStyle: {
    height: 100vh;
    backgroundColor: red;
  }
});
```

usage:

```
const classes = useStyles();

<Grid className={classes.gridStyle}>
     //....Code goes here...
</Grid>
```

Reference and other options: https://material-ui.com/styles/basics/

Let me know if this works. Glad to help further!